# How do I make a footer component in reactstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am using reactstrap to build a sticky footer component like this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) but I cannot find  a dedicated footer component.

The only other way is to just use html:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

The problem is the above is not picking my `.footer` class. That is a different problem, but for now I just want to know if there is a better way.

Footer is only defined in [Cards](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/#Header-and-Footer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In React we do not use `class` but `className` attribute. Normally it'll throw an error.
2. Your example uses an additional CSS `sticky-footer-navbar.css` file provide by Bootstrap that is not provide by default with the compiled code. You have to include it by yourself after get it on their source code on Github [Sticky Footer Navbar CSS Source Code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/site/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/sticky-footer-navbar.css)

Comment: Thabjs @mcssym. How do I include it, I could not find any documentation of this css file in bootstrap 4 anywhere.

Comment: as i said it is inclded with their source code on Github. Or you can get it here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/site/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/sticky-footer-navbar.css

Comment: i see, but I checked its  just for additional style. I thought it also affected the 'stickiness'

Comment: Affect how? I think it does the job if you want what it is on bootstrap example.

Comment: Links are 404'd

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to separate Footer component. Just add div like you're doing in the above code.

p.s. `class` = `className` in react.js.